# Power BI Custom Visual: Store Expand/Collapse State of a matrix like in default matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

i am implementing a default matrix like visual and want implement the possibility to expand/collapse rows and store this state:
[Expand/Collapse Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9As3k.png)

I am already had the feature to expand/collapse rows.

How do i store this information, so that on reload/refresh of the page, i can setup the same expand/collapse state for each row?

Answer (score 0):

check the image below. There's an expand/collapse all button.
[image]